# Can't set up an @Async method

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I'm trying to use the `@Async` annotation in my Spring project. To do so, I added this line to my servlet-config.xml :
`<task:annotation-driven />`. As a consequence, I can't run the project anymore and I get this error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.dynamease.web.user.social.LinkedInController]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
```

Here is my LinkedInController class :

```
@Controller
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class LinkedInController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LinkedInController.class);

    private final LinkedIn linkedIn;

    @Inject
    public LinkedInController(LinkedIn linkedIn) {
        logger.info("Initialisation du controleur linkedIn.");
        this.linkedIn = linkedIn;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "linkedin")
    public ModelAndView categorize() {
        categorizeAndStore(linkedIn);
        return mav;
    }

    @Async
    public Future<Boolean> categorizeAndStore( LinkedIn source) {
        // java stuff
        return new AsyncResult<Boolean>(true);
    }
}
```

The solution I found was to add `<aop:scoped-proxy>` or `@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)` but as you can see, its presence doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If aspects are applied to a class using a CGLIB proxy, a constructor with no argument is required. Try with something like this :

```
@Controller
public class LinkedInController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LinkedInController.class);

    @Inject
    private final LinkedIn linkedIn;

    public LinkedInController() {
        logger.info("Initialisation du controleur linkedIn.");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "linkedin")
    public ModelAndView categorize() {
        categorizeAndStore(linkedIn);
        return mav;
    }

    @Async
    public Future<Boolean> categorizeAndStore( LinkedIn source) {
        // java stuff
        return new AsyncResult<Boolean>(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it does run know and I'm thankful for that :) 
However, the categorizeAndStore() method is not executed asynchronymously, any ideas why ?

Comment: The method has to be called from a different object, if you call the method from within the same object it isn't intercepted...keep in mind that it use AOP... http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies